# Android 2.3 "start failed -2147483648" mediaRecorder error

Tags: android, api, video, mediarecorder

On Android 2.2 the code works fine on 2.3 it crashes at MediaRecorder.start() though. The log and the code itself is below. As you see it doesn't give much information, log gives "start failed -2147483648" message. I've been trying for ages and can't figure this one out, what am I doing wrong?

```
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

    try {
        camera.unlock();

        mediaRecorder.setCamera(camera);

        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

        mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO).toString());

        mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(cameraPreview.getHolder().getSurface());

        mediaRecorder.prepare();

        mediaRecorder.start(); // thats the line code fails

        fightTimer.start();
    } 
    catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Sorry, camera is currently not available"+ex.toString(), 2000).show();
    } 
    catch (IOException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Sorry, camera is currently not available"+ex.toString(), 2000).show();
    }
```

and log

```
08-13 06:34:56.914: I/MediaRecorderJNI(2256): prepare: surface=0x2bb230 (identity=13)
08-13 06:34:57.764: E/MediaRecorder(2256): start failed: -2147483648
```

Comment: Do you have the relevant permissions?

Comment: yes I do, all this works fine on Android 2.2

Comment: Sorry for posting in this old thread but how did you solved this error my code is working on 2.3 but crashes on 4.0

Answer (score 0):

That's just a bad error code. However, the first line `prepare: surface` indicates something related to constructing the VideoPlayer bounds and suddenly an exception occurs.

Do you need to `setVideoSize()`, maybe?

**TIP:** I'd search for "android mediarecorder start failed" (without the error code - it seems like those error codes are just as random as the error message itself! )

**EDIT:**
Since it works on Android 2.2, did you look at the API changes between API 2.2 and API 2.3 for MediaRecorder?

Comment: I have video size etc. set via CamcorderProfile with quality HIGH, I actually tried to set these values manually and the result was the same :(